# Ler tabela sqlite e inserir conteudo em listview

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, listview

Estou tentando inserir o conteúdo de uma Table em `sqlite` dentro de um `listview`. A table em Sqlite ja esta preenchida, a listview estava sendo preenchida com resultado do `webservice`, que tambem funciona ok, porém estou guardando os valores em um Sqlite para que a consulta seja mais rápida da proxima vez que o usuário acessar. Aparece o seguinte erro no logcat ao tentar inserir na listview:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.

Segue o código abaixo o erro acontece entra na linha `categoria_produtoList.add(0, member);`

```
public List<Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria> getAll() {
    List<Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria> foos = new ArrayList< Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria>();
    Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria member = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("Select * FROM " + NOME_TABELA_TERMOS_USO, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                member = new Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria();
                member.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                member.setPCT_ID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PCT_ID")));
                member.setDescricaoInternet(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DescricaoInternet")));
                member.setPossui_tamanho(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Possui_tamanho")));

                foos.add(member);

                Log.d("Categoria",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DescricaoInternet")));

                categoria_produtoList.add(0, member);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return foos;
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é esse `categoria_produtoList`? É seu listview?

Comment: Na verdade é a classe que representa a tabela no BD-DAO private List<Ac_Df_Produto_Categoria> categoria_produtoList;